# Editor not Replacing Text Area and Not Displaying on Page

Tags: html, ckeditor

I ran sample file (samples/replacebyclass.html) in several browsers on nmy development machine and the result was a large blank space following the label "Editor 1:"

I changed the `<script>` tag to point to the ckeditor.js  in my production website.  Then I reran the html page and got the expected and desired result.

I have tried copying the ckeditor.js, config.js, and contents.css doen from my website to my development machine but that had no discernible effect on the results.

There must be something in the ckeditor folder on my development machine that is different, but I cannot seem to identify it.

I sure do not want to move my ckeditor folder from my development machine up to the website (where ckeditor is working fine) until I can get the devel;opment machine to reliably render the editor like it is beinbg rendered on the website.

The environment is IIS and Windows server 2008 on the website and IIS Express on the development machine.

I really would like some suggestions on how to make this work on the development machine *Windows 10).

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the culprit.

Because an html page on my dev machine would work if the  tag pointed to the production *ckeditor.js* but that same html page did NOT work when the  tag pointed to the *ckeditor.js* on the dev machine, i reasoned that the problem had to be localized to the versioning of the ckeditor folder contents on both machines.

While I had copied over the *ckeditor.js*, *config.js*, and contents.css files from the production website's ckeditor folder, I failed to recognize that the *ckeditor/skins/bootstrapck* folder was different on dev vs prod.

When I copied over the *ckeditor/skins/bootstrapck* folder from prod, the text area now displays the editor and the contained text correctly.

Idf there is not already one, I would recommend that the ckeditor site publish the recommended "minimalist" ckeditor directory structure.